# How to run and manage multiple WebSocket clients in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, websocket

My goal is:

1. Connect and listen to many Web Sockets
2. Ping each of the connection
3. For some reason, the only framework that worked me was [websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/)
4. I want to be able to add more client sockets connections dynamically during runtime.
   However, websocket-client is sync library, and rel is blocking. So I have no idea how to resolve the issue.
   The code is working fine, but the issue is explained above.
5. First I'm defining websocket related data like url, ping interval, ping payload and etc.
   **token** from **open_tokens_ws** is sent once thed connection is established.

```py
import rel
import sys
import json
import random
import requests
import websocket
from threading import Timer, Thread

websocket.enableTrace(False)
WS_URL = "wss://url.com"
PING_INTERVAL = 20
PING_PAYLOAD = "p"

open_tokens_ws = {
    "name": "{\"t\":1,\"d\":\"{\\\"token\\\":\\\"********\\\"}\"}"
}

# The cookies I'm providing to websocket
cookies = {...}

headers = {
# The headers I'm prodiving to websocket
}

def zero_mask_key(_):
    return "\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

2. The helper class InfiniteTimer(). I use it for pinging purposes.

```py
class InfiniteTimer():
    def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
        self.t = t
        self.hFunction = hFunction
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.daemon = True

    def handle_function(self):
        self.hFunction()
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.thread.cancel()
```

3. And finally, WebSocket class.

```py
class WebSocketClient():
    def __init__(self, url, profile):
        self.WS_URL = url
        self.profile = profile
    
    def on_message(self, wsapp, message):
        print(message)
    
    def on_open(self, wsapp):
        print(f'[ {self.profile} ] Socket connection opened')
        self.wsapp.send(open_tokens_ws[self.profile])
        self.ping_timer.start()

    def on_close(self, wsapp, code, msg):
        print(f'[ {self.profile} ] Socket connection closed', code, msg)

    def on_error(self, wsapp, exc):
        print(f'[ {self.profile} ] Error: {exc}')
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    def connect(self):
        self.wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.WS_URL,
            header=headers,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            cookie=cookies[self.profile],
            on_open=self.on_open,
            on_close=self.on_close,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            get_mask_key=zero_mask_key,
        )
        self.ping_timer = InfiniteTimer(PING_INTERVAL, self.send_ping)
        self.wsapp.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=5)
        #rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
        #rel.dispatch()
        #print('Keyboard interrupt, stopping')

    def send_ping(self):
        self.wsapp.send(PING_PAYLOAD)

def main():
    for name in open_tokens_ws:
        ws = WebSocketClient(WS_URL, name)
        ws.connect()

    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)
    rel.dispatch()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've also been considering to use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) in order to run multiple python processes for each websocket client. Though, I run my python app with pipenv, so I want to know how to do that as well properly.